# Code conversion to other language

Tags: compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, interpreter

I am writing an interpreter for a toy language, using Antlr4, which essentially interprets the toy language's code and executes with Java's equivalent. For instance, i = 0, would create an entry in a Java's hashmap, with key as 'i' and value as an integer of value 0. So, Java is needed to interpret the toy language and execute. My question is, this is how in general interpreters work (depending on other language)? Otherwise, Is there any category of interpreters work like this?

Comment: How else would you create a compiler and interpreter? You have to create them in *some* language.

Comment: And that *some* language may be yours if you bootstrap and self host your own language compiler.